# About the solution of the differential equation for a circle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say you have the following differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=- \frac{x}{y}$$
what is the solution?

Obviously one can solve to get $x^2 +y^2 = r^2$ implying a circle. If we introduce initial conditions such as the point (0,1) what is the solution? Is it going to be full circle or is it going to be one branch of it?

More generally, when one talks about a solution curve does this imply that it is a requirement that there needs to be a maximum of one value of $y$ associated with each $x$? And moreover, how does one differentiate between different branches (given initial conditions)? Is it deviding the plane between the regions where $dy/dx=\infty$  ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A (classical) solution to an ODE on an interval $I$
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x, y(x))
$$
is a differentiable function
$$
y: I \to \mathbb R
$$
such that $y$ satisfies the ODE. Hence it can only have one value for each $x$. In the circle example, you can only have differentiable solutions away from $y = 0$ as the derivative diverges, so your solutions will be the semi circles not containing the points on the $x$ axis. If you wanted the initial condition $y(1) = 0$ then you would have to say that the initial condition is that
$$
\lim_{x \to 1}y = 0.
$$
This gives two solutions.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Could you clarify why  $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} y=0$ implies two solutions?

Comment: Also, if there are two solutions am I right in thinking that the initial condition tells us it is one of them and not that it is both? (since you require a maximum of one value of y associated with one value of x)

Comment: Both the semicircle above the $x$ axis and the one below satisfy the ODE and initial condition and are hence solutions. There isn't any reason to choose one over the other.

Comment: If instead you have an initial condition away from $y=0$ then this will uniquely determine which bit of the semicircle you are on.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have quick question, do the lines where $dy/dx= \infty$ seperate the different solutions?

Comment: Yeah, this is true for this case, and almost true in general I think - there are uniqueness results for ODEs when the function f(x, y) is sufficiently well behaved (see, for example, https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/50807#subsection.1.3). If your initial data point is not on $y = 0$ then locally around that point you have a unique solution since the function $x/y$ is bounded near your initial point, but this argument fails when $y = 0$, and indeed there are two possible solutions

Comment: thank you very much for the answer it is all clear to me now.